# How do I do a wildcard subdomain on MacOS 10.15?

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx, wordpress, wordpress-mu

I have setup `localhost/~<username>` and `~/Sites` on my computer and I am using `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to make custom testing domains. How do I add DNS wildcard domains? (`*.dev.server`)

I have setup Wordpress Multisite Network on ~/Sites/Wordpress (as `wordpress.server`) and whenever I make a site, it doesn't work. How do I get it to function?

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/<username>/Sites/Wordpress"
    ServerName wordpress.server
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.server
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    wordpress.server
127.0.0.1    www.wordpress.server
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'll need the help of [`dnsproxy.py`](https://gist.github.com/argv0/1327912).

## Prepare `dnsproxy.py`

First, download the Python file and move it into your home directory.
[Download it here](https://gist.github.com/argv0/1327912/archive/483bfcc68085ddcb88f30cc7a26b3374957a3e95.zip) then unzip the file. Next, move the Python file into your home directory. (`Users/<your username>`)

## Add wildard to `/etc/hosts`

Use your favourite editor, such as `nano`, to open the hosts file through Terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1       *.wordpress.server
```

## Run `dnsproxy.py`

Run `dnsproxy.py` by executing the following in Terminal:

```
python ~/dnsproxy.py -s 8.8.8.8
```

`-s 8.8.8.8` refers to a delegating DNS server. In this command, we're using Google's DNS Server. If you want, you can replace it with another DNS server. (such as 1.1.1.1)

If you encounter an error when using the `python` command in MacOS Catalina 10.15, try running the following:

```
/usr/bin/python ~/dnsproxy.py -s 8.8.8.8
```

Note: **Do not close or terminate the Terminal window, otherwise the wildcard in `/etc/hosts` will not work.**

## Add wildcard to `httpd-vhosts.conf`

In Terminal, using your preferred editor, open the following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Add the following entry: (Replace `wordpress.server` with your server's name and `Wordpress` with your project folder)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/<your username>/Sites/Wordpress"
    ServerName wordpress.server
    ServerAlias *.wordpress.server
</VirtualHost>
```

`ServerName` defines the main hostname, while `ServerAlias` defines the wildcard subdomains.

## Modify your DNS

Go to System Preferences ( > System Preferences...) and go to Network preferences.
[image: Network Preferences in System Preferences]

Then go to Advanced in the bottom-left corner of the pane. 
[image: Network Preferences in System Preferences]

Go to the DNS tab at the top of the pane.
[image: Network Preferences in System Preferences]

Next, add `127.0.0.1` as a DNS server. (If you have no entries and you're adding `127.0.0.1`, I recommend you add your network's default DNS or another DNS such as `8.8.8.8` so your Internet works when your not developing.)
[image: Network Preferences in System Preferences]

Lastly, click OK in the bottom-right corner of the pane, then click Apply.

## Check for errors

Execute the following command in Terminal:

```
apachectl configtest
```

It may display a few warnings, but in the end, it should result in `Syntax OK`.

If it doesn't display `Syntax OK` and results in errors, go to the file where the error is resulting and try to repair it.

## Restart Apache

Execute the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Now try to access a random subdomain, such as `test.wordpress.server`. It should work.

Comment: Remark that `*.wordpress.server` is not a valid `/etc/hosts` entry, so I'll keep it in a separate file. The **dnsproxy.py** script has an important parameter (`-s`) which must be provided: the address of a DNS resolver to send requests, which can not be answered from the `hosts` file. Also `/etc/resolv.conf` must be modified if you want your system to use the **dnsproxy.py** script.

Comment: Sorry @PiotrP.Karwasz I was writing this before bed and I was too sleepy to remember the `-s` parameter. Just one question: Should we edit `/etc/resolv.conf` or should we add a file to `/etc/resolver/wordpress.server`?

Comment: I figured it out, I just need to add it `127.0.0.1` as a DNS server in System Preferences.

Comment: Both should work: in `/etc/resolv.conf` **dnsproxy.py** will be used for everything, in the second location just for `wordpress.server`.

Comment: For beginners, it's easier to modify it in System Preferences than go and change the file. That way, (hopefully) no (syntax) errors occur.